# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, typeerror

I've been trying to send message to a particular text channel in a server using the channelId but I end up getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

when using

```
  const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('711580200315650078');
```

here is my entire code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;

bot.login(TOKEN);

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.info(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
  const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('711580200315650078');
  channel.send('hello');
  
});
```

Comment: Which version of Discord JS are you using?

Comment: @Jakye thanks . that indeed was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;

bot.login(TOKEN);

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.info(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
  const channel = bot.channels.get('711580200315650078');
  channel.send('hello');
  
});
```

This is probably because you're using Discord.js v11. You should migrate to v12, using `npm install discord.js`. You will then be able to use:

```js
const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('711580200315650078');
```

Comment: thank you. the problem was solved after migrating to v12.